# How do i fix the layout problem in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, resolution, aspect

Im trying to build a replica of the game 'Breakout'.

when i build and run the game in unity it looks good and everything id the correct scale but when i build and run the project on my laptop all the elements change size and some of the elements dont change size and i am not sure if i have done anything wrong or if i have forgotten to do something to stop it from changing.

This is what the game looks like in the unity editor when playing the game:

[image]

And this is what it looks like once i build and run the project on my computer:

[image]

My resolution is set to stand alone.

is there a way to get it to look like it does in the unity editor when i build and run it on my computer because that is what its supposed to look like.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html#constant-physical-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, there are many different screen sizes, and resolutions.

My favorite solution is to use a reference resolution that can expand but never shrink. This allows you to have a safe zone that stays consistent across different screen sizes. For a generic case, you would use **16:9** aspect ratio, with the resolution of either **1280x720** or **1920x1080**.

[image: resolution]

In Unity, on your canvas, modify the **Canvas Scaler** such that **UI Scale Mode** is set to **Scale with Screen Size**. Add your reference resolution, and set the **Screen Match Mode** to **Expand**.

[image: canvas-scaler]

In the **Game** tab you can preview what 16:9 looks like. You can try out other aspect ratios or resolutions.

[image: resolutions]

For example, the iPhone 11 has a much wider resolution, so it expands horizontally. It's up to you to design your UI in a way that makes sense. You can either keep everything in the safe zone or align elements to the corners of the screen.

[image]